# function and statements not covered in istanbul and jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, istanbul

I'm using https://istanbul.js.org/ for Code coverage and https://jestjs.io/ for unit testing on the following sendMail function. However, I keep getting Istanbul coverage error that the function `function(error, info)` and the statements `return console.log(error);` and `console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);` are not covered. In the code, I only call `sendMail()` and I have no idea what elase I need to do to stop the coverage errors. Any advice and ideas? Thanks so much!!

```
sendMail() {    
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
        if(error){
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
    });
}
```

jest test case:

```
test("send email test", () => {        
        sendMail();        
    });
```

Comment: Well you don't pass a callback

Comment: thanks, not sure how to test that. I only called sendMail()

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the wrapper had the same name and thought you were testing that. Forget what I said.

Comment: thanks Aluan. Any ideas what i missed to stop the Istanbul coverage error?

Comment: I'm not certain but, for other reasons like readability, I would promisify that method. `transporter.sendMail = utils.promisify(transporter.sendMail)`

Comment: What's `transporter`? please provide the code.

Comment: let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(options[, defaults]) I found createTransport() in https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/blob/master/lib/nodemailer.js#L25